# Add subview to NSTextView underneath text

Tags: swift, subclass, nstextview

How can i add a subview to my NSTextView subclass such that it lies beneath the text as per the image below?

[image]

Comment: NSTextView is a subclass of NSText which is a subclass of NSView, so inherits all the properties and methods of NSView.  You should be able to do anything you want in the drawRect method.

Comment: I want to add other subviews though? Including NSTextFields

Comment: So look at NSView's addSubView or maybe addSubView:positioned:relativeTo:.  NSTextViews are (back to basics) NSViews.  You have an NSTextView and you want to add a sub view. Look at the class reference for NSView.  Create a subclass of NSView, do what you want in the drawRect method, instantiate it and add it as a sub view to your NSTextView.

Comment: NSTextView and NSTextField both derive from NSView.  They will both have a drawRect Method.  Actually you may want to sub class NSTextField or NSTextView depending on your needs.

Comment: addSubView:positioned:relativeTo: is what i wanted, I subclassed the superview of my NSTextView and added my subview below it. Thanks!